# c++ .NET background worker invoke

Tags: .net, c++-cli, invoke

I'm trying to change mu UI control using a backgroundworker. I read about Control->Invoke() class but I don't know ho to use it in C++.
This is what I got:

```
System::Void check_new() {
                p = ((Label^)napisy[IdNadawca])->Location;
                System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pb = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
                koperty[System::Convert::ToInt32(((Label^)napisy[IdNadawca])->Name)] = pb;
                pb->Location = System::Drawing::Point(p);
                pb->Left = 755;
                pb->Name = (System::Convert::ToString(IdNadawca));
                pb->Size = System::Drawing::Size(30, 20);
                pb->TabIndex = 2;
                pb->TabStop = false;
                pb->Image= (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"koperta_mala")));
                Controls->Add(pb);
            }
```

This function (called by backgroundworker) creates a picturebox in UI.
The thing is, I don't know how to access UI using background thread.

Comment: The point of using BackgroundWorker is to *not* have to write this kind of code.  You should use the RunWorkerCompleted and (perhaps) the ProgressChanged events.  They are fired on the UI thread so you don't have to jump through the Begin/Invoke() hoop.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is a never ending backgound thread. It should work endless.
In my class contructor I have this:

` IniBackground();
background->RunWorkerAsync();`


and


`code System::Void IniBackground() {
     background->DoWork += gcnew DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Komunikator::Okienko::DoBackground);
    }

System::Void DoBackground(Object^ sender, DoWorkEventArgs^ e) {
 while(!worker->CancellationPending) chech_new();
    }`

Comment: Well, use the ProgressChanged event then.  You do after all have progress to display.  Pass anything that the event handler needs to do its job through ReportProgress' *state* argument.

Comment: But can ProgressChanged edit controls in UI?

Comment: As noted, the event is fired on the UI thread.  So yes.

Comment: So, I followed your advices and this is what i have now:
 System::Void IniBackground() { background->DoWork += gcnew DoWorkEventHandler(this, &Komunikator::Okienko::DoBackground);
 background->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this,&Komunikator::Okienko::show);
    }

and
System::Void DoBackground(Object^ sender, DoWorkEventArgs^ e) {
 BackgroundWorker^ worker = dynamic_cast<BackgroundWorker^>(sender);
 while (!worker->CancellationPending) {
 check_new();
 } 

System::Void show(Object^ sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^ e) { Controls->Add(object); 
    }

Comment: The thing is it works for around 5 secondsand then nothing

Comment: Standard bugs are forgetting to check e.Error in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  And firehosing the UI thread so it burns 100% core and stops being responsive, add Thread.Sleep(45) to the loop to see if that makes a difference.